# Robovm bindings import issue

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, robovm

I am trying to import the RoboVM bindings to implement mopub in my project, but I ran into a problem when I tried to "build model". I tried to import it as a gradle project, but when I build it I get the error:

```
"Error in runnable 'Creating Gradle Model'"
```

And it says:

```
"could not find com.github.jtakakura:gradle-robovm-plugin:0.0.9-SNAPSHOT.
Required by:
:robovm-ios-bindings-master:unspecified
See error log for details"
```

in the error log it said

> "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred configuring root project 'robovm-ios-bindings-master'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find com.github.jtakakura:gradle-robovm-plugin:0.0.9-SNAPSHOT.
>        Required by:
>            :robovm-ios-bindings-master:unspecified
>
> Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output."

I am not even sure how to run with the stacktrace option, does anyone have any insight on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Okay so it seems like I shouldn't be importing the binding project as a gradle project, because I had it working in a different workspace, and it looks like I had it imported as a normal project. The only problem is that I redownloaded the bindings to see if they would work. Now if I try to reopen the project in the workspace which had it working, it says I am missing the .project file. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it out! I went into the ios bindings folder, opened the build.gradle, and found the line of code that had the 0.0.9-SNAPSHOT. Then I went to the github for robovm, and opened the build.gradle there. I saw that it had 0.0.10 as the snapshot, so I changed it to that. It now works, and I feel pretty brilliant for that.