# RoboVM imports wont work - The import org.robovm.apple cannot be resolved

Tags: java, ios, binding, import, robovm

I have a libGDX game that i have finally been able to get it to work on iOS, desktop and Android all now without issues. I wanted to put google adMob ads into my iOS project and began by using the bindings i found [here](https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings) . I had trouble importing them which was nearly the same issue as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23862504/robovm-bindings-import-issue) and solved using the solution from that post as well. Now that i have been able to import the admob-ios project, in all of the classes within it they all have the same begining error with their imports saying things like

```
The import org.robovm.apple cannot be resolved
```

This must somehow be because of an inaccessible library but i cant figure out how. For example in the "GADAdMobExtras.java" file it begins by importing

```
import org.robovm.apple.foundation.NSDictionary;
import org.robovm.objc.annotation.NativeClass;
import org.robovm.objc.annotation.Property;
```

All of which have the cannot be resolved import error. Each of these classes are also riddled with errors that I must assume are just because nothing can be imported.

I am running libGDX 1.2.0, and RoboVM for eclipse plugin 0.0.14, and have also tried with the robovm nightlies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, in the "ext" section of the build.gradle file for the main ios-bindings project, they still have the version for your local RoboVM plugin set to "0.0.14-SNAPSHOT", mine was the release of 0.0.14 so just take the snapshot off in the build.gradle. I have also tested compatibility with the 0.0.15-SNAPSHOT and that does now also work correctly.

ie:

```
ext {
roboVMVersion = '0.0.15-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

should be changed to whatever version you are running. I suppose it is just an overlooking on my part but sure was difficult to find!

Good Luck!